# Can I get the beanIOItemReader record number in an ItemProcessor when using Jberet?

Tags: jberet

I am using a chunk to read a file and insert the contents into a database, one of the columns in the table requires the record number from the input file. Is there a way to get that in the object passed to the ItemProcessor or to get it from within the ItemProcessor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using an ItemReadListener to get the StepContext metrics in the afterRead method and updating my Object read with the current read count.

Answer (score 0):

JBeret `BeanIOItemReader` delegates all operations to the underlying `org.beanio.BeanReader`. So if you need that information from the input, then you'll need to configure your BeanIO mapping file to include that in the DTO used by `BeanReader`.

If you need to access the cumulative stats, you can probably look in `javax.batch.runtime.context.StepContext#getMetrics`, where you can access various stats:

```
        READ_COUNT
        WRITE_COUNT
        COMMIT_COUNT
        ROLLBACK_COUNT
        READ_SKIP_COUNT
        PROCESS_SKIP_COUNT
        FILTER_COUNT
        WRITE_SKIP_COUNT
```

Comment: Do you have an example of configuring the mapping to do this?

Comment: Please see https://github.com/jberet/jberet-support/blob/master/src/test/resources/person-beanio-mapping.xml for example. This mapping file is used by the test https://github.com/jberet/jberet-support/blob/master/src/test/java/org/jberet/support/io/BeanIOReaderWriterTest.java

Comment: I looked at the example above and just don't understand. For each record read I need the beanio reader record number so I can write that to the database.

Comment: can you give example what you mean by 'reader record number'?

Comment: BeanReader has the method: public int getRecordCount();
I need to be able to get the record count/number of the record passed to the ItemProcessor.

Answer (score 0):

`BeanReader.getRecordCount()` javadoc describes it as:

```java
    /**
     * Returns the number of records read from the underlying input stream for the
     * most recent bean object read from this reader.  This typically returns 1
     * unless a bean object was mapped to a record group which may span
     * multiple records.
     * @return the record count
     * @since 2.0
     */
    public int getRecordCount();
```

If it typically returns 1, then I don't see how it can be useful.

If you want to know the number of records the reader has been reading, i.e., 5th, or 6th records, then you can use batch metrics `READ_COUNT` as described above.